# Bootstrap collapsable nav not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, collapsable

The collapse-able part wont work. (this part)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GmVR.jpg)

Here is the code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Connor Clarke</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Games</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: Do you have bootstrap js included and are you using a jquery library as well?

Comment: David, I click the button and it does nothing. Jake,  I have bootstrap js included and I know it works because It worked earlier. I done nothing to it since then and when I came back to it later It would not do anything when I click.

Comment: You need both jQuery (first) and the Bootstrap JS file (second) in order for *collapse* to work. You should also check your browser's console for errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you provided works fine so the error you are seeing must have something to do with other code on the page. Most likely reasons are

1. You are missing references to the Bootstrap JavaScript or CSS files.
2. You are missing jQuery.
3. You have not put jQuery *before* the Bootstrap JavaScript reference.
4. There is another JavaScript error on the page, look in your browsers console for errors.

Example of your code working:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Connor Clarke</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Games</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Another common issue is loading *another* jQuery JS file after the Bootstrap one

Comment: @Phil I have a feeling that adding another jQuery would make the entire nav not show at all, but you could be right.

Comment: The nav appearance is due to CSS. Adding another jQuery just blows away the Bootstrap JS plugins as `jQuery.fn` is emptied